# How do I run a standard SQL query without breaking BigQuery Connector for Excel?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to run the following query.  It is valid and works in the web ui

```
SELECT * FROM `option-optimizer.cme.3months_euro_dollar_future` 
where date = '2017-09-01'
```

but it doesn't work when I run it through the BigQuery Connector for Excel.  It doesn't seem to recognize the standard SQL format.  Here's the error I get.

```
Request failed: Error. Unable to execute query. 400 {
  "code": 400,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "location": "`option-optimizer:cme.3months_euro_dollar_future`",
      "locationType": "other",
      "message": "Invalid table name: `option-optimizer:cme.3months_euro_dollar_future`\n[Try using standard SQL (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)].",
      "reason": "invalid"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Invalid table name: `option-optimizer:cme.3months_euro_dollar_future`\n[Try using standard SQL (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)]."
}
```

In addition to above error, I think the date filter would also break.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run queries using standard SQL, prefix your query with the following line:

```
#standardSQL
```

for example:

```
#standardSQL   
SELECT * FROM `option-optimizer.cme.3months_euro_dollar_future` 
where date = '2017-09-01'
```